# Problemas al desplazar un jlabel (animación)

Tags: java

Verán, yo tengo una librería llamada RSAnimation para mover componentes de un punto a otro y que se vea la animación, está librería tiene varios métodos para mover de un lado al otro, los métodos reciben 5 argumentos (posición inicial, posición final, retardo, salto, componente) , por ahora lo uso en un hilo para hacer que en un fondo se cambien por otro de la siguiente forma

```
public void fondo_desplazamiento({

 Thread thread = new Thread(()->
        while(true){

            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
               fondo1.setVisible(true);
               RSAnimation(-750, 100, 5, 5, fondo2);
               RSAnimation(70, 750, 5, 5, fondo1);
               Thread.sleep(5000);
               RSAnimation(-750, 70, 5, 5, fondo1);
               RSAnimation(100, 800, 5, 5, fondo1);
               Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
}
```

El problema es que tengo un botón que abre un menú emergente y cuando se realiza la animación pues se antepone sobre el menú a pesar de que los fondos están de últimos y no deja ver qué hay en el menú mientras se ejecuta el hilo de animación, quisiera saber si hay una forma de que los labels se muestren siempre en el fondo sin anteponerse a los demás componentes, también acepto sugerencias si existe una mejor forma de hacer esa animación.

Comment: Se que no tiene nada que ver con lo que preguntas, pero ¿el retardo es la velocidad a la que se mueve? y ¿salto que es?

Comment: Retardo es la velocidad con la que llega de un punto a otro expresado en segundos y salto es la cantidad de pixel que se desplaza a la vez

Comment: lo unico que se me ocurre es la solucion obvia, es dejar ese boton fijo en un area del jframe donde no pasen las componentes en movimiento.

Comment: El problema no es el botón, es que yo tengo un menú que aparece cuando se selecciona el botón, el menú aparece en un costado, y la animación le pasa por encima.